# Icon and menubar are changing geometry

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, icons, menubar

I want to save the geometry of my tkinter widget in a config file, but I discovered that the combination of an icon and a menubar changes the printed geometry.

In the following code the geometry is set to 800x**500**+200+200, but upon closing the widget, it prints 800x**480**+200+200 (hope this is reproducible - works for any icon in my case). After saving and reloading the geometry, my widget therefore becomes smaller with every run.

If either removing the menubar or the icon, the 500 are printed on close, so only the combination of both raises this issue.

```
import tkinter as tk

class NewGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('800x500+200+200')
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",  self.on_close)
        self.root.iconbitmap('C:\Program Files\Python39\DLLs\pyc.ico')

        menubar = tk.Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)
        menubar.add_command(label="Settings")

        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_close(self):
        print(self.root.geometry())
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = NewGUI()
```

Comment: Try calling `self.root.update` after `self.root.iconbitmap`. I think this fixes it because `update` will make tkinter recalculate the window dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! `self.root.update()` with parentheses solved it!